# How to Post Comment using GitHub OAuth Token in Angular 2

Tags: angular, post, typescript, github, oauth

I'm trying to use GitHub OAuth Token to post comment in Angular 2. My code is

```
  postComment(token: string, number: Number, body: string): Promise<Comment> {
let headers = new Headers()
headers.append('Authorization', `token ${token}`)
return this.http
  .post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${this.GITHUB_USERNAME}/${this.GITHUB_POST_REPO}/issues/${number}/comments`, {body}, {
    headers: headers
  }).toPromise()
  .then(res => res.json() as Comment)
  }
```

But it doesn't work, I alway get the reponse like this :

```
{
  "message": "Issue not viewable by PoiScript",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

By the way, I'm trying to post comment in **issues** instead of pr or commit.

Comment: What is Poiscript? Is it your app name? It might be your permissions setup.

Comment: No, PoiScript is my username. I'm using my token and I have already included it in the HTTP header... I don't kwon what I missed...

Comment: Does the token provided by your user have the right permissions? It seems it doesn't.

Comment: Eh... I alredy use `curl -H "Authorization: token <token>" https://api.github.com/user` to check and it's valid..

Comment: When you authorize an app (even if it's yours) you dictate what you allow the app to access. It looks like the given token is not allowed to access the given repo. If it's a private repo it should have the `repo` permission. Take a look at https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes to check what permissions you need to do each action.

Comment: Oh... that makes sense, I wil try it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, it works! Thank you again!

Comment: I've added the answer below with the response to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your permissions, if you don't have the `repo` permission the API will not allow you to access private repositories.